# weighted least square and Difference in Difference matching

Tags: weighted-regression

I have two period panel datasets and I am trying to do research based on Propensity score matching-cum-Difference in Difference methods (in combination). Khandker et al. (2010) and Hirano, Imbens, and Ridder (2003) recommend weighted least square with the following regression specification by weighting the control observations in line with their propensity score.
〖ΔY〗_it=α+〖βT〗_i+ γΔΧ_it+ ε_it  ,
β= Diff in Diff estimate; T_i= Treatment indicator (1 for participant, o else)
For an estimate of the ATE for the population, they recommend the weights would be 1⁄(P ̂(X)) for the participants and 1⁄((1-P ̂(X)) ) for the control group
I am using STATA 13 but get problem in applying weighted least square (WLS) regression. Specifically the weights are on treatment indicator and it seems that there are two weights, for participants and for non-participants. So which one to use and how?
What could be the stata syntax to fix it?
Is weighted least square a must for PSM-cum-DiD matching? Is it subject to prior heterosckedasticity check or understood because of the associated matching (blocks/strata)? Is there any other regressions-other than WLS regression- possible (like for instance diff in diff using Time dummy t, Treatment dummy T, and their interactions? 
Many thanks!